# Programatically created Like Button leaks huge amounts of Memory

Tags: javascript, facebook

I'm working on a pure Javascript Application that needs to create Facebook Like Buttons programatically (RSS News Reader). Unfortunately this isn't viable because repeatedly creating Like Buttons leaks huge amounts of memory in a short time.

I've created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oliverw/G2qkc/3/) that demonstrates the problem (just watch the memory consumption for the jsFiddle Tab continously increase and never recover). Any suggestions on how to prevent this from happening would be appreciated.

P.S: Ironically, the Google+ Like button has the same problem.

Comment: nothing happened here (Chrome & Firefox)

Comment: I think he's referring to IE.  Microsoft's solution: [refresh the browser](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/263863).  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure the issue is just that your 1000ms timeout doesn't give the garbage collector time to run.

Try profiling this: http://jsfiddle.net/G2qkc/4/

It makes the timeout 10 seconds long every 20th time. On my machine at least, the memory gets reclaimed when you give the GC a chance to breathe.

Your app is probably fine. Looks like the test was flawed.

Comment: Unfortunately my app has the same problem without any loop, just normal usage.